# Value cannot be null. C#

Tags: c#

Im trying to get an `int[] array` but it's returning an error which is **Value cannot be null**. I'm still a newbie to c#. Can someone help or give a clue how to solve this? I tried many techniques of passing the value but still no luck.

here's where the array came from

```
    private void btnTag_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<int> employee_id_list = new List<int>();
        foreach (Control c in panelEmployee.Controls)
        {
            if (c is CheckBox)
            {
                if (((CheckBox)c).Checked)
                {
                    employee_id_list.Add(Convert.ToInt32(c.Tag));
                }
            }
        }

        var type = Type.GetType("Payroll." + dynamic_form);
        dynamic form = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as Form;
        form.GetEmployeeID(employee_id_list.ToArray());
        this.Close();

    }
```

here's where i displayed it

```
    public int[] emp_id;

    public void GetEmployeeID(int[] employee_id)
    {
        emp_id = employee_id;
        //in this code there are no errors and it is showing the array
        MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, emp_id));
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // but when i trigger this it returns and error Value cannot be null
        MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, emp_id));
    }
```

Comment: Make sure to call GetEmployeeID before calling btnSave_Click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you lose the value of the variable `emp_id` between the `GetEmployee` call (it assigns value to `emp_id` from the parameter so it will work always you pass a not null value) and the later call to `btnSave_Click`that is trying to use the previously( and hopefully) assigned value of `emp_id`

Maybe you are using WebForms , in that case you should assign the emp_id to a Session state or something that won't get deleted on next request.

```
public int[] emp_id;

public void GetEmployeeID(int[] employee_id)
{
    emp_id = employee_id;
    //in this code there are no errors and it is showing the array
    MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, emp_id));
}

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // but when i trigger this it returns and error Value cannot be null
    MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, emp_id));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea and comment. I changed the `public int[]` to `public static int[]`. Thanks bro.